# Why is this not being read as numeric when I specify it?

Tags: r, csv

I've narrowed it down to a very small example so I'm sure it's something very silly.

I have the file `test.delete` with these contents:

```
Rock,bird
1350909372121900000,55.20000
1350909372318100000,55.30000
1350909382020900000,55.20000
1350909382029600000,55.20000
1350909384311100000,55.20000
```

and then I do:

```
test = read.csv('test.delete', colClasses=c('character','numeric'))
```

but all columns seem to be read in as character:

```
> apply(test, 2, class)
       Rock        bird
"character" "character"
```

Why is this?

Comment: From `?apply`: "If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read.csv` is working as you want. You're misusing `apply` here.

If you run `str` on the imported data, you should see that the other variable is numeric. But when you call `apply`, the data frame is coerced to a matrix, which only handles one data type, and everything is coerced to character.

As safer way to check the column classes would be to use `lapply`, since a data.frame is in reality a list.

Comment: All this time I've been using `sapply(names(dat), function(x) class(dat$x))`. But `sapply(dat,class)` is so much cleaner. D'oh.